# Issues with Terraform creating a string of IP addresses

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to create EC2 VMs with the following resource declaration using Terraform.

```
resource "aws_instance" "wurststand" {
  for_each = toset(["bratwurst-01", "bratwurst-02", "bratwurst-03", "currywurst-01", "currywurst-02" , "hotdog-01"])
  ami = "ami-0c9354388bb36c088"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "wurststand"

  tags = {
    name = each.key
  }
}
```

Now I need the public_ip addresses of all Bratwurst instances in one string. To create a group_vars file for ansible that fills a JINJA2 template again. How do I do this. I already tried to solder this with join but somehow Terraform doesn't like it.

The final result should look like this: 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "I already tried to solder this with join but somehow Terraform doesn't like it." Edit your question to show your attempt, and show the error or unexpected behavior that resulted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [for expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for) to extract the list of IPs from the set of `aws_instance` resources, and then pass that to `join`:

```
join(", ", [for i in aws_instance.wurststand : i.private_ip])
```

Comment: @SYN As per the documentation here: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat "The splat expression patterns shown above apply only to lists, sets, and tuples. To get a similar result with a map or object value you must use for expressions.

Resources that use the for_each argument will appear in expressions as a map of objects, so you can't use splat expressions with those resources. "

Comment: Thanks for this informations it helped much. But how to prevent that the currywurst and the hotdog will appear to?

Answer (score 0):

So this is my solution with which it does what I want.

```
resource "aws_instance" "wurststand" {
  for_each = toset(["bratwurst-01", "bratwurst-02", "currywurst-01", "currywurst-02", "currywurst-03", "hotdog-01", "logstash-01"])
  ami = "ami-0c9354388bb36c088"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "wurststand"

  tags = {
    Name = each.key
  }
}

resource "local_file" "inventory" {
  content = templatefile("templates/inventory.tftpl", {
    elastic = tomap({
       for instance in aws_instance.wurststand:
        instance.tags.Name => instance.public_ip
      })
  })
  filename = format("%s/%s", abspath(path.root), "../ansible/inventory/inventory.cfg")
}

resource "local_file" "bratwurst_hosts_for_group_vars" {
  content = templatefile("templates/bratwurst_groupvars.tftpl", {
    hosts = join("\" , \"", [for i in aws_instance.wurststand: i.public_ip if contains("bratwurst", i.tags.Name)])
  })
  filename = format("%s/%s", abspath(path.root), "../ansible/group_vars/Bratwurst.yml")
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.